# How to program the spring MVC cron without annotation

Tags: spring, cron, annotations

```java
package com.test.cron; 

@Service 

public class CronJob { 
    protected static final Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(CronJob.class);

    @Scheduled(cron="0 0 23 * * *")
    public void demoServiceMethod()
    {
        logger.debug("Cron job started.");
    }
}
```

Cron excution time will be often changed.
I have to exchange '@Scheduled' annotation to java code.

Answer (score 2):

You can **externalize** this cron value into a properties file.

```
@Scheduled(cron="${schedularTime}")
```

and in your properties file ( example: application-dev.properties)

```
schedularTime=0 0/2 * * * ?
```

Answer (score 1):

Old thread, but there is no real answer to the question.

Here is a way to schedule jobs without any annotations.
The example is in Kotlin, but works the same way in java.

```kotlin
@Component
class CliRunner(
    private val scheduler: ThreadPoolTaskScheduler,
    private val scheduledService: ScheduledService
) : CommandLineRunner {

    override fun run(vararg args: String) {
        scheduler.scheduleAtFixedRate(scheduledService::run, 10_000)
    }
}
```

Inject `ThreadPoolTaskScheduler` and whatever you want to schedule, and call any of the scheduling methods on the scheduler.

My example schedules the run method to be executed every 10 seconds.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a database for the configuration of schedule, Quartz had a capability to save its job meta data in a datasource.
Somebody had implemented something like this here.

https://github.com/davidkiss/spring-boot-quartz-demo